# Providing the direction path from one point to another in Open Layer 3

Tags: openlayers-3

Is there any API in Open Layer 3 for direction between two location in map?
I tried to search the API for direction but I got the result of pg routing.

Comment: what I understood from your question,that  you want to Implement the client side routing using openlayers, right?

Comment: Ya.I want like when they select Source and destination route should plot.Is there any API for that? Thanks in advance

Comment: you can use [pgRouting](http://pgrouting.org/) api but it is server side